# How to determine whether two barcode images are different?

Tags: image-processing, barcode

I have to barcode images, and I need to decide whether they are different.

[image]

[image]

I have tried reading the image and then comparing pixels but this seems like a hack, and it's difficult to properly align the two images.

What are some good approaches for this?

Comment: **decode** them.

Comment: It would be two images. Sometimes the barcodes would be the same, and sometimes they would be different. I need to decide whether the images are the same or not

Comment: I need to determine whether the barcodes are the same or not

Comment: I can't decode them because the quality is not always high enough to do so

Comment: if the barcodes are **unreadable**, it is **impossible** to determine if they're the same. you didn't say that's a problem in your question.

Comment: Yes it is possible. I can tell by eye that they are different without knowing the decoding of the barcode

Comment: please review [mre]. present data.

Comment: @ThanksABundle Your picture links are broken. Do you have links to the pages you sourced them from? _"I can tell by eye that they are different"_ so which part do you need us for? If your images are isolated bar codes (black on white bg), then you can crop by finding first top-left and last bottom-right pixel to know rectangle boundary. You can scale them to same size and **image differencing** where you check if each black pixel matches at same position in the other image.

Comment: those broken image links are broken due to a copy-paste error (pasted links somewhere else before, that then abbreviated them with a ..., and OP then copied that abbreviated link, thinking it's good, never ever checking why the pics don't show up in the question). *and* they're **stock photos** anyway. I just googled. they're meaningless to this question. both are perfectly decodable pictures of random codes. *that* is why people ask for a proper MRE, because this question is unanswerable and OP seems to have given up already.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned OS/programming language constraints so I will answer with the two options I'm aware of

1. If it's a one-off comparation, you can install [`zbar`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/). If you use Ubuntu, you can install it as follows

```bash
sudo apt-get install zbar-tools
```

or the equivalent in the package manager of your distro. If you are stuck with windows, not sure if you can install it, but it's worth a shot looking. Once you install it, you can use it like this:

```bash
zbarimg "image-file-name.jpg"
```

and it will decode the contents of the QR. Doing this for both QRs will allow to diff both outputs and check whether they have the same contents or not (credit for this part [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22871/software-to-read-a-qr-code))

2. If you want to perform a programmatic comparation or you are more of a python guy, you can use [`pyzbar`](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/) which is a python wrapper of the above library. the idea would be the same: you would decode both QRs and compare their contents

Comment: unfortunately, OP said that some codes are not decodable.

Comment: Then it's a fool's errand. If you can't decode them, you can only perform a binary comparison, and byte-per-byte you are almost 100% guaranteed that the images are distinct so it's no harm considering all of them distinct. In that case, I'd tell OP that run `diff -s qr1.jpg qr2.jpg` and call it a day.

Comment: "fool's errand", exactly my point but OP didn't like being told as much in the comments.